# Cypher : representing nested graphs?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, redisgraph

How would you represent graph of graphs in Graph DB.
F.e. mnemonically it may look like this :

```
((a)->(b))->(c)
((a)->(b))->((c)->(d))
```

In a sense (a)->(b) for (c) act as a single node, but is internally two linked nodes.
And of course you should be able to nest them further.

Is there some graph structure that I can use to represent this.

---

```
  (a)<-[:1]-(ab)-[:2]->(b)
  (ab)<-[:1]-(abc)-[:2]->(c)
```

???

---

@bouteillebleu : second variant

```
 (a)-[:fst]->(ab)-[:snd]->(b)
 (ab)->(c)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would be simple in Neo4J, I admi. Is this a general question about how to implement graphs where one node is also a graph, or are you trying to model something else with this data structure? If you're trying to model something else, there may be other ways to do that.

Comment: For example, if you wanted to say "the relationship between A and B is itself related to C", then you could do that by rather than having A -> B just being represented by an edge, having A -> X -> B (turning the previous relationship into a node itself) and then adding a relationship X -> C.

Comment: Please remove your directed comments from your question. That's not the place to have a discussion (and adds confusion to the question itself).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest and most concise way for a node to reference an entire subgraph of any size and complexity would be to store in that node a `cypher` property whose value is a Cypher query string that would produce the desired subgraph.

As an example, here's how you might represent the assertion that a specific `subgraph1` contains a given `subgraph2`:

```
CREATE
  (subgraph1:Graph {cypher: 'MATCH p=(f:Foo)-[:HAS]->(:Bar) WHERE f.id = 123 RETURN p'}),
  (subgraph2:Graph {cypher: 'MATCH (f:Foo) WHERE f.id = 123 RETURN f'}),
  (subgraph1)-[:CONTAINS]->(subgraph2)
```

If the actual subgraph represented by `subgraph1` consisted of several billion nodes and relationships, there may be no other practical way to represent the subgraph.

Comment: Another option may be to create "supernodes" herarchical above subgraphs. I've done this for chromosome segments which overlap but are relatable and an edge to a supernode can connect them.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf That does not work if a subgraph is not supposed to contain *all* of the relationships between the nodes connected to the "supernodes". But, yes, for some use cases it would work and be practical.